Spring app runs well on local machine and through docker image, but when I deploy the app in render through that docker image, it’s not working well
I have built a web app with the help of react, spring and postgres. My app works perfectly fine on the local machine and through the docker image while signing with localhost:8080/login which I defined in the formLogin’s login page. But when I’m deploying the web app to render platform, it throws a 404 error while the react app send a request to ____.onrender.com/login. Does anyone face the same problem before or does anyone know how to overcome it?
This is my SecurityConfig:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private String[] publicUrls = {.....};
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private AllUsersService allUsersService;
    private UsersService usersService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService, AllUsersService allUsersService, UsersService usersService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.allUsersService = allUsersService;
        this.usersService = usersService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(config -> config
                .requestMatchers(publicUrls).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    
                    // Upon successful login, send a 200 ok response
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Login successful\"}");
                })
                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                    // Upon failed login, send a 401 Unauthorized response
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Invalid email or password\"}");
                })
        ).logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    // Return a JSON response
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Logout successful\"}");
                })
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

   
    // CORS configuration
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(-102);

        return bean;
    }
}

This is my login request sent from react frontend:
const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login",
                {
                    username,
                    password
                },
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                }
            )
            if (response.status === 200) {
                window.location.href = "/home";
            }
        }
        catch (error) { 
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    alert("Invalid email or password");
                }
            }
        }
    }

The app runs perfectly well when I run it on my local machine or through the docker image with this login implementation. But I face problem when deploying the app on render.
This is my login request sent from react frontend after deployed the backend to render:
const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://-----.onrender.com/login",
                {
                    username,
                    password
                },
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }enter image description here
                }
            )
            if (response.status === 200) {
                window.location.href = "/home";
            }
        }
        catch (error) { 
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    alert("Invalid email or password");
                }
            }
        }
    }

This throws a 404 error saying that,
Screenshot of the error message
As I'm deploying my spring app to render through a docker image, where the docker image runs without any issue but when deployed to render it shows this error.
I'm new in this production environment and I would highly appreciate your feedback. I want the deployed app to works perfectly fine on render platform as it was working fine through docker image

This is most likely to be problem of hosting platform not in your code share logs of render.
